# Problem with Firebase Firestore when calling on App Delegate swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a firestore call every time the app launches. but the line of accessing firestore or the completion is not being executed.

```
class MoodAnalysisFirestoreManager{

private let db = Firestore.firestore()
static let shared =  MoodAnalysisFirestoreManager()
private let currentUser =  AuthManager.shared().getCurrentUserSafe()!

private init(){}

  public func addNewDayToCloud(){
    
    let todayName = Date().getTodayName(date: Date()).uppercased()
    let safeDate = safeDateString(date: Date())

    let ref = db.collection("MoodAnalysis").document(currentUser)
    ref.collection("analysis").document(safeDate).setData([
        "day": todayName,
        "date": Date(),
        "neutralCount": 0,
        "angryCount": 0,
        "sadCount": 0,
        "happyCount": 0,
        "Count":0,
        "emotionVal":0
    ]){
        error in
        print(error)
    }
    
}
```

app delegate function

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    print(db)
    MoodAnalysisFirestoreManager.shared.addNewDayToCloud()
    return true
}
```

if I called `MoodAnalysisFirestoreManager.shared.addNewDayToCloud()` from the app delegate it does not add anything to the firestore, but if I make any type of retrieving data from the cloud it works fine or, calls this function in other view controllers everything works fine.

Comment: Which app delegate method do you call from?

Comment: this func didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: That will only execute each time your app is launched, not each time it opens from suspension. You should [edit] your question to show how you call this function.

Comment: I edited it, but it still has the same problem it does not execute in any case whether the app is launched or opened.

Comment: Add breakpoints in `addNewDayToCloud` and your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to see how far your application gets. Does it print an error?

Comment: Did you check to see if `currentUser` is nil? (if not, you should be). I would also suggest moving that code from the AppDelegate to the first viewController. Generally speaking it's not delegate related code - it's Firebase code and would probably be better suited to be called from your initial viewController. (totally IMO).

Comment: currentUser is not nil. it works for me after I moved the code to the first view controller.

Comment: Does that mean the issue is resolved? (when responding to a comment be sure to get that users attention by prefacing their name with an at sign, like @Jay)

Comment: @Jay yeah it resolved with moving from app delegate to the first view controller